# symfony jquery don't work after load(window.location)

Tags: ajax, symfony

after a ajax success call i reload a div or table from id

```
$.ajax({

   success: function (data) {

           alert(data['risultato']);
           $("#div_id").load(window.location + " #div_id");

        },
        error: function(){
        }

    });
```

but always after this in that #div_id reloaded   the jquery that before work , after doesn't work anymore .

I see that if before ajax call the html of my div (in that case table_id) is :

```
<table class="responsive-table" id="address_list">


               </table>
```

after is :

```
<table class="responsive-table" id="address_list">
   <table class="responsive-table" id="address_list">                       

               </table>
</table>
```

if i write

$("#address_list").load(location.href+" #address_list>*","");

is not replicate but after jquery don't work anyway

Why it happens??

Comment: Can you all your code?

Comment: is not in a part of code ...all div i will try to reload jquery after don't work... in my case now is a table_id and when a i delete a row with ajax and  reload $("#table_id").load(window.location + " #table_id") the jquery don't work anymore in that div

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `id` more one in one HTML page. Error because you have two id's in your HTML page.

Comment: ok but this reload  $("#div_id").load(window.location + " #div_id");  create a new div under div_id??  if i want only reload the current div how i can do?

Answer (score 0):

I understan my wrong  ... in

jquery event i change

$('.mdi-navigation-close').click(function () {

on

$('body').on('click','.mdi-navigation-close', function(){